# JQuery ternary operator does not execute logic the proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, razor

**I want to have dynamic rendering button with 2 styles based on `isAssigned` variable:**

if `isAssigned` is false I want button to look like this
`<button class="btn btn-success-outlined" data-action="join">Join</button>`
it have to redirect to Join controller method

if `isAssigned` is true I want it to look like this
`<button class="btn btn-success" data-action="leave">Joined</button>`
it has to redirect to Leave controller method

Problem is that no matter what `isAssigned` value it is, it just gets the first possible outcome of my conditional operator, in this case button is always like this `<button class="btn btn-success" data-action="leave">Joined</button>`

Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var referenceLinkButton = document.getElementById("referenceLinkButton");
    var referenceLink = referenceLinkButton.dataset.referenceUrl;

    referenceLinkButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (isValidURL(referenceLink)) {
            window.open(referenceLink, "_blank");
        }
    });

    function isValidURL(url) {
        var pattern = /^(https?:\/\/)/i;
        return pattern.test(url);
    }

    // Use the global variables defined in the Razor view
    let data = {
        encodedName: encodedName,
        isAssigned: isAssigned
    };

    const container = $("#buttons")

    function RenderJoinButton(data, container) {
        container.empty();
        const button = data.isAssigned
            ? `<button class="btn btn-success" data-action="leave">Joined</button>`
            : `<button class="btn btn-success-outlined" data-action="join">Join</button>`

        container.append(button);

        container.find('[data-action="join"]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const encodedName = $(this).data('encodedname');
            navigateToProjectManagerEdit(encodedName);
        });

        container.find('[data-action="leave"]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const encodedName = $(this).data('encodedname');
            navigateToTaskManagerIndex(encodedName);
        });
    };

    RenderJoinButton(data, container)
});
```

`isAssigned` value is assigned correct, tried to debug it with `console.log`, also it is not overridden by other JS code, I don't have idea what is wrong with it. Switching it into if else also did not help

this is part of my view for reference

```html
@model TaskManager.Application.Task.TaskDto

...

<div class="card-footer" id="buttons">
       <!-- Js will populate this-->          
</div>

rest of the code...

<script>
    var encodedName = "@Html.Raw(Model.EncodedName)";
    var isAssigned = "@Html.Raw(Model.IsAssigned)";
</script>
<script src="~/js/TaskManager/Details.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the type and value of `isAssigned`? What are you getting?

Comment: Note that because of the way `isAssigned` (the global variable) is set, it will be a string with `"True"` or `"False"`, depending on what .NET language you are using. You are probably better off doing `var isAssigned = @(Model.IsAssigned ? "true" : "false");` instead.

Comment: Please see [ask], then simplify the code in your question to just what's needed for your problem. We don't need to see Razor code. A bit of HTML and your jQuery function should do.

Comment: @Andy I used typeof operator to checked it - somehow it is string, i dont know honestly because in TaskDto model i have it clearly set as bool but this is likely the issue

Comment: Because you put quotes around it in the `var isAssigned` statement.

Comment: Since you render your global isAssigned variable as string it is always 'truthy' in JavaScript. You can either update your statement to check if data.isAssigned === "True" or change how you initialize global variables -> var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); and then use model.isAssigned

Comment: "*it works now*" - please provide an answer or close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was wrong method of pasing variable from my razor view into JS code

```
    var isAssigned = "@Html.Raw(Model.IsAssigned)";
```

by this approach boolean value was pharsed into string so it was 'true' or 'false' (with quotes)

To fix it i had to modify this line as follows:

```
    var isAssigned = @(Model.IsAssigned ? "true" : "false");
```

by this approach isAssigned variable remains boolean and it can operate within ternary operator